# Run a JS script in WordPress after JQuery has loaded

Tags: jquery

I try to run this script in WP but it does not work. I need it runs after that jQuery has loaded, I use a theme called "Jupiter".

In functions.php of my child folder

```
function my_scripts_method() {
    wp_register_script('custom_script',
   get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/sort_members.js',
   array('jquery'),
   '1.0' );
   wp_enqueue_script('custom_script');
  }
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method');
```

In my sort_members.js

```
 (function($) {        

$(document).ready(function() { 
    var alphabeticallyOrderedDivs = $('.member-name').sort(function(a, b) {     

        return 
    String.prototype.localeCompare.call($(a).data('lastname').toLowerCase(), 
       $(b).data('lastname').toLowerCase()); 
    });

    var container = $('.team-member');
    container.detach().empty().append(alphabeticallyOrderedDivs);
    $('body').append(container);})
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: This gist is a starting point. It uses setTimeout to keep checking if Window.jQuery exists. Once it does, call your function that needs jQuery. https://gist.github.com/madeindjs/7ea13d03d6699f5f84761a12bff86ff5

Comment: sorry i don't know how to use this...

Comment: Based on the way register works, this should work as it has jQuery as a dependency. What's the error message?

Comment: i have no error but my main content is not displayed...

Comment: i also tried to put directly in the page in the defer function $(document).ready(function()